# paperclip image path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am still very new to ruby (finishing a class on it now) so please be very specific with me. For my class final, I am making a simple blog and trying to get an image uploader working using paperclip. The problem is that it while it saves all of the images, I can't see or use them in a post. I've been through every tutorial I can find and all the paperclip documentation and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I would like the images to save in my public/images folder if possible, but at this point I will take just being able to use the ones saved in the systems folder. Any help at all on this is appreciated.

My files are: Imagelist (which displays all the urls)

```
class Imagelist < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :image

  attr_accessor :image_file_name
  attr_accessor :image_content_type
  attr_accessor :image_file_size
  attr_accessor :image_updated_at
  attr_accessor :image_url

  has_attached_file :image
end
```

And add_image_to_imagelist (add images to the imagelist)

```
class AddImageToImagelists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :imagelists, :image_file_name,       :string
    add_column :imagelists, :image_content_type,    :string
    add_column :imagelists, :image_file_size,       :integer
    add_column :imagelists, :image_updated_at,      :datetime

    add_attachment :imagelists, :image
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :imagelists, :image_file_name
    remove_column :imagelists, :image_content_type
    remove_column :imagelists, :image_file_size
    remove_column :imagelists, :image_updated_at

    remove_attachment :imagelists, :image
  end
end
```

My show.html.rb file

```
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @imagelist.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  <%= @imagelist.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Image:</b>
    <br />
    <%= image_tag @imagelist.image.url %>
    <br />
    <%= link_to @imagelist.image.url, @imagelist.image.url %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_imagelist_path(@imagelist) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', imagelists_path %>
```

Am I just calling the image url wrong? At the moment, all the show.html can find is /images/original/missing.png file.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if there is something saved in the following fields in your database table:

```
image_file_name, image_content_type, image_file_size and image_updated_at
```

Try removing the attr_accessor method from the ImageList model.

Comment: Removing the attr_accessor methods gets me this error: Imagelist model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'. I need those to get it to show.

I checked the database and while the imagelists table is creating a space for that image info, it is not getting filled in. How would I get it to fill in the image name, url, etc.? I don't have an image table at all. Could that be the problem?